# Problems with jquery ajax on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I am using ajax to load contents from another page to show in the footer. It work  fine in ff, chrome, safari, and opera, but it is not working in Internet Explorer. I do not have much experience in jQuery. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(" #footer #achive-box ,.related-archives .archive-post")
        .load("/_blog/Member_Area_Articles/ .show-archive .BlogPostArchive");

    $(".show-archive .BlogPostArchive").css("display", "block");
});
```

Comment: mean the contents i want to show on footer not shoeing in internet explorer and also there is no error is found in firebug.

Comment: Version # of IE please?

Comment: The version of IE 8 and IE 7.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the element `.show-archive .BlogPostArchive` is loaded by the `load` method which is asynchronous in nature, so, the display code has to be moved to the load complete callback

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(" #footer #achive-box ,.related-archives .archive-post")
    .load("/_blog/Member_Area_Articles/ .show-archive .BlogPostArchive", function(){
        $(".show-archive .BlogPostArchive").css("display", "block");
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm confused why this isn't working for the OP in *only* IE though. This is how it should be done anyways

Comment: ahh totally agree.  Ian you need a callback function to use the selectors you are loading onto the page.  I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

If your AJAX code is working in every other browser, then its probably a cache issue because previous files are still associated to your current window?  Clear your cache in IE, close your browser, all active session accounts, and re-open it and see.